# Why is the derivative of this Gaussian Function negative before being positive?

Tags: real-analysis, quantum-mechanics, gaussian

From pg. 61 of *Principles of Quantum Mechanics*, the Guassian $g_Δ$ is defined as

$$
g_Δ(x-x') = \frac{1}{(πΔ^2)^{1/2}} \exp \left[ -\frac{(x-x')^2}{Δ^2} \right]
$$

where the Gaussian is centered at $x'=x$, has width $\Delta$, maximum height $(π Δ^2)^{-1/2}$, and has unit area (independent of $Δ$). In case it matters, we can assume that $Δ ∈ \mathbb{R}$.

**Problem:** The book goes on to display the derivative of $g_\Delta$ as follows:

> [image]

It seems to me the derivative graph (b) is wrong, since it is negative when $x' < x$ and positive when $x' > x$. Isn't this exactly backwards, and if not, why?

---

**EDIT for bounty:** The crux of my confusion lies in understanding/getting a different viewpoint for why

$$
\frac{dg_\Delta(x-x')}{dx} = -\frac{dg_\Delta(x-x')}{dx'}
$$

Moreover, is this actually a general theorem, or is this using something special about $g_\Delta$ in particular?  That is, if we let $x,' \in \mathbb{R}$ and consider $f(x-x')$ as an arbitrary real function, do we have in general that

$$
\frac{df(x-x')}{dx} = -\frac{df(x-x')}{dx'}?
$$

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: It looks like the error is that the roles of $x$ and $x^\prime$ have been switched in the figure.

Comment: I think all equations of your text are fine, and the author has not flipped anything. The ordinate on (b) is a function of x',  $dg_\Delta (x-x')/dx=-dg_\Delta (x-x')/dx'$, the slopes are consistent with that, and the sampling is exactly right. It is somewhat perverse and unusual to use $\delta '(x-x')$ as defined, inside the integral, but correct.

Comment: @CosmasZachos I'm confused why changing the variable from $x'$ to $x$ has the result of flipping the positivity/negativity of $g$.  It seems to me that this is equivalent to switching from $g_\Delta(x-x')$  (where $g$ is a function of $x$) to $g_\Delta (-(x-x'))$.  That is, when we change variables like this, we are merely flipping $g$ around the vertical axis, which doesn't change its shape (thus the derivative should continue to be positive, then negative).  What am I missing? :]

Comment: @CosmasZachos Put differently, $g$ is an **even function**, so changing variables like this shouldn't change the shape of its graph (so shouldn't change the shape of the graph of its derivative, either).  Unless I'm missing something :]

Comment: @CosmasZachos I just realized that the Gaussian function is not even unless $x = 0$, but I'm still totally confused by this graph.  While $g$ isn't even in general, it still seems symmetric when you flip it across the horizontal axis.  It still seems to me the derivative should be positive before it's negative, and now it (further) seems to me the derivative inflection point should be centered at $-x$, not $x$, due to the change in variable from $x'$ to $x$.

Comment: @CosmasZachos I was flat wrong, and I now understand that the graphs and equations as presented in the book are correct (aside from one remaining issue: the inflection point of the derivative graph should be based around $-x$, not $x$).  Simply drawing a picture helps visualize how $\frac{d}{dx'}g_\Delta(x-x') = -\frac{d}{dx'}g_\Delta(x'-x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the chain rule.

For any differentiable function,

$$\frac d{dx}f(x-x')=-\frac d{dx'}f(x-x')$$ just because

$$\frac d{dx}(x-x')=1$$ and $$\frac d{dx'}(x-x')=-1.$$

The plot in the book is correct because the dérivative is on $x$, while the axis is $x'$.

Comment: This makes sense except when I confuse myself with an example:

Let $f(x) = 0$ if $x \le 0$ and $f(x) = x$ if $x > 0$.  Let $f_{x}(x-x')$ and $f_{x'}(x-x')$ be $f(x-x')$ viewed as a function of $x$ and $x'$, respectively.  For our consideration, suppose that $x' = 0$ when considering $f_x$ and $x = 0$ when considering $f_{x'}$.  Then $f_{x}(x-x') = f(x)$ and $f_{x'}(x-x') = f(-x')$. Considering the derivatives evaluated at $1$, how isn't $\frac{d}{dx}f_x(1-x')=\frac{d}{dx}f_x(1)=1 \ne 0 = -\frac{d}{dx'}f_{x'}(-1) =  -\frac{d}{dx'}f_{x'}(x-1)$ a counter-example to the general result?

Comment: I have a made a [separate post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4113206/how-is-this-not-a-counter-example-to-the-fact-that-frac-ddxfx-x-frac-d) with this question.

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$
h(x, x') = \frac{1}{(\pi \Delta^2)^{1/2}}e^{-\frac{(x - x')^2}{\Delta^2}}.
$$
Notice that
$$
\frac{\partial h(x,x')}{\partial x} = \frac{1}{(\pi \Delta^2)^{1/2}}e^{-\frac{(x - x')^2}{\Delta^2}} \left(-\frac{2(x - x')}{\Delta^2} \right).
$$
Plotted as a function of $x$, with $x'$ held fixed, the graph of $\frac{\partial h(x,x')}{\partial x}$ looks like this, as you would expect:

[image]

However, the author Shankar (confusingly) plots $\frac{\partial h(x,x')}{\partial x}$ as a function of $x'$, with $x$ held fixed. The resulting plot looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this rewriting is clear.
The crux of the issue seems to be that
$$ \xi(x,x'):=x-x'$$
satisfies
$$ \partial_x\xi(x,x')=1=-\partial_{x'}\xi(x,x').$$
Here $\partial_x := \frac{d}{d x}$ is shorthand. Then for each fixed $x,x'$, and any one variable function $f$, we can apply chain rule
$$ \partial_x (f\circ \xi)(x,x') = f'(\xi(x,x'))\partial_x \xi(x,x') = - f'(\xi(x,x'))\partial_{x'} \xi(x,x') = - \partial_{x'} (f\circ \xi)(x,x').$$
This is what I would understand as the meaning of
$$ \frac{df(x-x')}{dx} = -\frac{df(x-x')}{dx'}.$$
One could also proceed without chain rule; since
$$ \frac{f((x+h)-x')-f(x-x')}{h} = \frac{f(x-(x'-h))-f(x-x')}{h} = -\frac{f(x-(x'-h))-f(x-x')}{-h}$$
we have
\begin{align}
\frac{df(x-x')}{dx}
&=\lim_{h\to0} \frac{f((x+h)-x')-f(x-x')}{h}\\
&=-\lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(x-(x'-h))-f(x-x')}{-h}\\
&=-\lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(x-(x'+h))-f(x-x')}{h}\\
&=-\frac{df(x-x')}{dx'}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Rotate your coordinate system *(x,x')* by 45 degrees. For a function $g_\Delta (x-x')$ even in $x-x'$, you have
$$
\frac{ d g_\Delta (x-x')}{dx} =- \frac{d g_\Delta (x-x')}{d x' },  \tag{1.10.20}
$$
so the ordinate of (b) is an odd function, by convention called $  g_\Delta ' (x-x')$, but really $- d g_\Delta (x-x')/d x' $, so minus the derivative of (a) w.r.t. *x*'.

To the left of *x*, this is negative, because $  g_\Delta ' (x-x')>0.$ Its minimum is at $x'=x-\epsilon$, and its maximum is at $x'=x+\epsilon$. So
$$
  g_\Delta ' (x-x') \sim   \delta (x'-\epsilon-x) -\delta(x'-x +\epsilon )
$$
sampling the function *f* as the author claims, correctly.

---

*Note on your additional edit*:

Define $y\equiv x-x'$, the light-cone variable. It then follows that
$$
\frac{d }{dx} f(y) + \frac{d }{dx'} f(y) = \frac{d y }{dx}  \frac{d f(y) }{dy}  + \frac{d y }{dx'}  \frac{d f(y) }{dy}\\
 =   \frac{d f(y) }{dy}  - \frac{d f(y) }{dy}=0.
$$

Comment: What do you mean by the notation $dg_\Delta(x-x')/d(x+x')$ (specifically the $(d+x')$ term in the denominator is throwing me off, since I'm used to just seeing $dx$ in the denominator of derivative notation)?

Comment: This is a coordinate rotation to light cone orthogonal coordinates $(x,x')\mapsto( x+x',x-x')$ that you were taught, normalized by the Jacobian determinant, which I skip as irrelevant. You could use special new names for them, but what is the point?