# How is this not a counter-example to the fact that $\frac d{dx}f(x-x')=-\frac d{dx'}f(x-x')$?

Tags: real-analysis

**Theorem.** For any differentiable function,

$$\frac d{dx}f(x-x')=-\frac d{dx'}f(x-x')$$

since

$$\frac d{dx}(x-x')=1$$ and $$\frac d{dx'}(x-x')=-1.$$ The result follows from the chain rule.

**Counter-example?** The above theorem makes sense to me except when I confuse myself with an example: Let $f(x)=0$ if $x≤0$ and $f(x)=x$ if $x>0$. Let $f_x(x−x')$ and $f_{x'}(x−x')$ be $f(x−x')$ viewed as a function of x and x', respectively. For our consideration, suppose that $x'=0$ when considering $f_x$ and $x=0$ when considering $f_{x'}$. Then $f_x(x−x′)=f(x)$ and $f_{x'}(x−x′)=f(−x')$. Considering the derivatives evaluated at $1$, how isn't

$$
\frac{d}{dx}f_x(1-x')=\frac{d}{dx}f_x(1)=1 \ne 0 = -\frac{d}{dx'}f_{x'}(-1) =  -\frac{d}{dx'}f_{x'}(x-1)
$$

a counter-example to the above general result?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that you're considering two different points in the two evaluations. All of these computations are true:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x-y)\big|_{x=1,y=0} &=f'(1-0)=f'(1) = 1 \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x-y)\big|_{x=1,y=0} &=-f'(1-0)=-f'(1) = -1
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x-y)\big|_{x=0,y=1} &=f'(0-1)=f'(-1) = 0 \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x-y)\big|_{x=0,y=1} &=-f'(0-1)=-f'(-1) = 0
\end{align*}
But the OP tries to compare $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x-y)\big|_{x=1,y=0}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x-y)\big|_{x=0,y=1}$, which are unrelated.